# Комбинированный MYSQL запрос

Tags: mysql

Подскажите можно ли составить один универсальный MYSQL запрос в моем случае вместо пятидесяти отдельных?
Исходные данные, имеем число **number** = 5

**table1**

**id|number**

1|3

2|5

3|6

Из таблицы 1 нужно получить уникальный **id** для этого номера, известно что он один, если конечно такая запись имеется, в противном случае результат запроса будет пустым.
Результат запроса к первой таблице в нашем случае **id**=2;

**table2**

**uniq_id|id**

1|1

2|2

3|2

4|2

5|3

Из таблицы 2 нужно получить диапазон уникальных **uniq_id**, где **id** равняется результату прошлого запроса из таблицы 1, если они есть, в противном случае результат запроса должен быть пустым.
В данном случае это будут все **uniq_id** = 2,3,4

**table3**

**uniq_id**

1

2

3

5

Получить запись с максимальным существующим **uniq_id** в таблице 3 из диапазона, полученного из таблицы 2. В нашем случае это запись с **uniq_id**=3, если конечно такая запись имеется, в противном случае результат запроса будет пустым.

```
create table table1(id integer, num integer);
insert into table1(id, num) values(1, 3);
insert into table1(id, num) values(2, 5);
insert into table1(id, num) values(3, 6);

create table table2(uni_id integer, id integer);
insert into table2(uni_id, id) values(1, 1);
insert into table2(uni_id, id) values(2, 2);
insert into table2(uni_id, id) values(3, 2);
insert into table2(uni_id, id) values(4, 2);
insert into table2(uni_id, id) values(5, 3);

create table table3(uni_id integer);
insert into table3(uni_id) values(1);
insert into table3(uni_id) values(2);
insert into table3(uni_id) values(3);
insert into table3(uni_id) values(5);


select max(uni_id) from table3 where
    exists(select uni_id from table2 where 
            exists (select id from table1 where EXISTS (select * from table1 where num=5) and num=5)
                and id=(select id from table1 where EXISTS (select * from table1 where num=5) and num=5))
```

Не работает.

Comment: Да простой же запрос...

Comment: @Akina Поможете составить?

Comment: Я - только к ночи. Со смартфона неудобно...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SET @number := 5;

SELECT t3.uni_id
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 USING (id)
JOIN table3 t3 USING (uni_id)
WHERE t1.num = @number
ORDER BY t3.uni_id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6ce156ac0ef1d29343d63f4d811ea41d)

Comment: Тот же вопрос, в данном случае запрос возвращает саму запись или только максимальное значение ?

Comment: @deathnoob Нужна вся запись - напишите `SELECT *` вместо `SELECT t3.uni_id`, какие проблемы-то? тем более что вся запись - это и есть одно поле.

Comment: через SELECT * возвращаются 3 поля из разных таблиц, видимо связано с JOIN. А нужна лишь запись целиком с uni_id = 3

Comment: а вот, вроде разобрался, через SELECT t3.* возвращается вся запись.

Comment: Не дороговато будет сортировать? Легче уж max + limit 1  использовать.

Comment: @Miron A `MAX()` типа без сортировки обойдётся? Интересно, как...

Comment: @Miron Теоретически, в зависимости от кучи параметров массива данных и структуры хранения, с точки зрения производительности может оказаться немного выгоднее заменить последний JOIN на WHERE EXISTS. Ибо, по счастью, именно по полю сортировки выполняется последнее связывание.

Comment: @Akina легко. Сложность O(n) - один проход по "массиву". Сортировка же - минимум O(n log n)

Comment: @Miron Ну если таблицы офигенного размера и индексы отсутствуют как класс - может быть, может быть... к тому же я не знаю, как именно будет выполняться связывание - а при отсутствии индексов сервер вполне может выполнить предварительную сортировку.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    MAX(uniq_id) as max_uniq_id
FROM 
    table3
WHERE
    uniq_id in
    (SELECT 
        uniq_id
    FROM 
        table2
    WHERE 
        id IN 
        (SELECT
            id
        FROM 
            table1
        WHERE 
            num = 5));
```

P.S.: изменил название столбца у последних двух таблиц - `uniq_id`, а не `uni_id`

Comment: Возвращается запись таблицы 3? Или только максимальное значение? Нужна запись целиком.

Comment: SELECT * FROM table3 where uniq_id= (ваш код) . Вот так возвращается запись, можно ли это проще записать?

Comment: @deathnoob думаю, что это оптимальный вариант.

Comment: Это ужасно... WHERE IN и так-то тормоз изрядный, а уж два подряд...

Comment: @Akina хмм, не слышал о таком. Можно ссылочку на бенчмарки, показывающие это?